# get data from radio group in custom listview

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve data from radio group in custom listview and save that data to database but when I want to use the following code the app crashes. I tried different methods but none are working.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_attendence);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvshowattend);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("my data base", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from attendence ", null);
    name = new ArrayList<>();
    atten = new ArrayList<>();
    date = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            name.add(c.getString(0));
            atten.add(c.getString(1));
            date.add(c.getString(2));

    CustomAdapter c1 = new CustomAdapter(ShowAttendence.this, R.layout.row2, R.id.cstname, name);
    lv.setAdapter(c1);
        }
    }
    finally {
        c.close();
    }
}
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);
        TextView cname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cstname);
        TextView cattend = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cstattend);
        RadioGroup crg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.cstrg);
        RadioButton crbpr= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbpresent);
        RadioButton crbab= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbabsent);
        RadioButton crble= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbleave);
        cname.setText(name.get(position));
        cattend.setText(atten.get(position));
        int selectedId = crg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        return v;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: provide your crash log..

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: when i remove int selectedid= crg.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); then it is ok. but i want to retrive data from radio group. how it is possible

Comment: Post row2.xml layout

Comment: in row2.xml i have radio group with three radio buttons and two text view. i want to get check radio button value and textview value. i am not getting radio button  value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
crg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            //find radiobutton position
            int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) crg.getChildAt(position);
            String selection = (String) btn.getText();
        }
    });
```

instead of

```
 int selectedId = crg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
```

Also change this;

```
RadioGroup crg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.cstrg);
    RadioButton crbpr= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbpresent);
    RadioButton crbab= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbabsent);
    RadioButton crble= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.crbleave);
```

to

```
RadioGroup crg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.cstrg);
    RadioButton crbpr= (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.crbpresent);
    RadioButton crbab= (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.crbabsent);
    RadioButton crble= (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.crbleave);
```

Comment: same problem app crashes

Comment: i have edited the code...at which line crash occurs? it will be better if u upload the error log..

Comment: `
01-03 12:18:07.982 30455-30455/pk.apps.android.attendencesystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 12:18:07.982 30455-30455/pk.apps.android.attendencesystem E/AndroidRuntime: Process: pk.apps.android.attendencesystem, PID: 30455
01-03 12:18:07.982 30455-30455/pk.apps.android.attendencesystem E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
`

Comment: same error. app crashes. i want to get radio buton value and save it to database.